# Locking files on OSX are preventing from Gradle sync on android studio, the files are getting locked repeatedly even after deleting them

Tags: android, macos, android-gradle-plugin

I am creating a new Android Project and following are the details :-

OS : MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) and mc OS mojave. version 10.14.6,
Android studio version 3.5

While trying to Sync the project few files are getting locked and the sync is failing. Even after deleting them and killing the gradle demon and starting the Sync again the files are locked and sync fails.

Following is the detail of the error :-

' ERROR: Timeout waiting to lock Build Output Cleanup Cache 
 (/Volumes/MYNEWVOLUME/study_material/android/ReadText/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup). It is 
 currently in use by another Gradle instance.
 Owner PID: unknown
 Our PID: 8524
 Owner Operation: unknown
 Our operation:
 Lock file: 
/Volumes/MYNEWVOLUME/study_material/android/ReadText/.gradle/buildOutputCleanup/buildOutputCleanup.lock

'

I found out that when I start the sync two instances of gradle demon threads starts. If I try to kill any of them then Sync fails. If i let it run then one of the thread acquires the lock and other cannot get that and hence sync fails.

Below are the gradle details :-

```
    '
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.readtext"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}

Gradle build details are


        '

         // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub- 
         projects/modules.

         buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects  {


    repositories {
        google()

        jcenter ()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the error by changing the location of my android project. Create the project in the default directory suggested by android studio and the projects run and build fine without any error. In my case I initially was creating in a different directory as shown above /Volumes/MYNEWVOLUME/study_material/android/ReadText . But again after creating a new project in the default project directory of /user/XXXX/AndroidStudioProjects/ReadText. It started running perfectly without any locks.